# CRUD Booster Laravel database error

Tags: laravel

I am trying to install CRUDBooster in laravel.  Yet, I do not see the tables provided after the installation.  There are only two tables in the migration:
1.  create user tables
2.  create password reset tables

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project.cms_settings' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `cms_settings` where `name` = appname limit 1) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\crudbooster\vendor\crocodicstudio\crudbooster\src\views\login.blade.php)

When trying to run this url:  http://localhost/crudbooster/public/admin/login

I am following this tutorial:  http://crudbooster.com/doc/5.3/intro

How to set up the tables in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the error says that the table `cms_settings` in `project` database is missing. After running `composer require crocodicstudio/crudbooster`, you need to add the service provider

```
crocodicstudio\crudbooster\CRUDBoosterServiceProvider::class,
```

Then, on your terminal or cmd you need to run on the project root, I assumed `C:\xampp\htdocs\crudbooster`

```
php artisan crudbooster:install
```

The crudbooster will do the rest.

https://github.com/crocodic-studio/crudbooster/blob/master/docs/en/installation.md#how-to-install

Comment: I already try typing php artisan crudbooster:install and wait for an hour and it is not done yet.  Then, I have to stop.  How long does it take normally to run this command?

Comment: Using a XAMPP or any windows built-in database, like the windows version of MySql or MariaDB, may suffer an annoying delay on inserting data, and `php artisan crudbooster:install` is creating and inserting data to the database, (I assumed MySQL XAMPP). 

I highly suggest using a homestead (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead) or docker like (http://laradock.io/)

I am using Homestead with a fresh installation of Laravel and Crudbooster just to simulate your problem and by running `php artisan crudbooster:install` it only takes me a minute or 2.

Comment: I highly suggest of using homestead (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead) or laradock (http://laradock.io/). Its for Windows

Comment: Where to enter this comment:  git clone https://github.com/Laradock/laradock.git ?  In command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

That's mean your composer not create a table of migration.

Please, first follow this step : https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

After install CRUDbooster auto admin portal. I'm using very well CRUDbooster in laravel 5.4 and 5.6.